# Fullcalendar disable eventOrder

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

Hi everyone is defaultly ordering by start time, title etc but I'm already fetching feed with exact type we want.It overrides the orderline and brokes the orderline.
I'm fetching events with 2 type `type:1, type:2` but type 2 events must shown before type 1.

Also I'm using the limit with

```
   contentHeight:800,
        firstDay: 1,
   eventLimit: true, 

        views: {
            month: {
                eventLimit: 3
            }
        },
```

it shows 1 event and +more but I want to show 2 event each day.Why it happens.
Can i disable it. Thank you

http://jsfiddle.net/slyvain/waa23ry0/

I found this example it works but only the events starts in same time.Date overrides in sametime.I still got order them by title or something

Comment: Can I do this, or should I do what

Comment: I'm using fullcalendar with cdn, can I disable this default override

Comment: Tip: in future, add more (and more popular, but still relevant) tags to your question, to get more visibility for it. And please don't ask multiple questions in one post. You seem to be asking about event ordering and event limit. Don't do that, please post separate questions about separate problems.

Comment: Anyway, you can customise the event order to some extent - see the documentation here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/eventOrder

Answer (score 0):

According to FC `eventOrder` documentation, you can subscribe a custom property as a string:

`String / Array / Function, default: "start,-duration,allDay,title"`

**Example**

```js
{
    eventOrder: "-type"
}
```

With the minus sign, the ordering will appear in descending order (2 before 1).

ref: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventOrder